# How to login to AWS CodeArtifact before npm installs

Tags: npm-scripts, aws-codeartifact

How can I trigger the login before the install script in `node v18.12.1`/`npm 8.19.2`?

I expect the `npm` `preinstall` script will run before the `install` script based on [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config). When running `node v14.21.1`/`npm 6.14.17` I was able to follow the instructions [in this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/publishing-private-npm-packages-aws-codeartifact/) to trigger a CodeArtifact login with the `preinstall` script. All packages were installed from my CodeArtifact repository on running `npm install` as expected.

After updating to `node v18.12.1`/`npm 8.19.2`, `npm install` fails with error:

```
Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid
```

What I have tested (each in a fresh environment with no npm cache):

- `npm run preinstall` successfully logs on

  - ∴ AWS credentials are configured and the preinstall script works when executed
- `npm install` fails authentication
- `npm run preinstall; npm install` successfully logs on and installs from CodeArtifact

  - ∴ the preinstall script is not running. I get no results from filtering the debug logs suggesting the `co:login` step is not run:

```
$ cat /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-06T07_12_47_353Z-debug-0.log | grep co:login

$ echo $?
1
```

After reverting to `node v14.21.1`/`npm 6.14.17`, `npm install` behaves as expected, logging in and installing packages from CodeArtifact.
I have recreated the problem with a minimal `package.json` which can be tested in a docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro --name app node:18.12.1 /bin/bash
wget --quiet -O "awscliv2.zip" "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-$(uname -m).zip" && unzip -q awscliv2.zip
./aws/install
rm awscliv2.zip && rm -r ./aws
```

Copy files in from a separate terminal

```
docker cp package.json app:/package.json
docker cp package-lock.json app:/package-lock.json
```

And then install with `npm install` in the docker container.

`package.json` template would require you to substitute your own CodeArtifact repository, domain and owner

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "preinstall": "npm run co:login",
    "co:login": "aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repository --domain my-domain --domain-owner 123456789 --region ap-southeast-2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6"
  }
}
```

`package-lock.json` template would require you to substitute your own CodeArtifact url

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "dayjs": "^1.11.6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/dayjs": {
      "version": "1.11.6",
      "resolved": "https://mydomain-123456789.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443/npm/my-repository/dayjs/-/dayjs-1.11.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-zZbY5giJAinCG+7AGaw0wIhNZ6J8AhWuSXKvuc1KAyMiRsvGQWqh4L+MomvhdAYjN+lqvVCMq1I41e3YHvXkyQ=="
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dayjs": {
      "version": "1.11.6",
      "resolved": "https://mydomain-123456789.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443/npm/my-repository/dayjs/-/dayjs-1.11.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-zZbY5giJAinCG+7AGaw0wIhNZ6J8AhWuSXKvuc1KAyMiRsvGQWqh4L+MomvhdAYjN+lqvVCMq1I41e3YHvXkyQ=="
    }
  }
}
```